# My website's images are not opening on Iphones

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

My website contains images, and both automatic and manual slideshows all of them are opening on android perfectly, but on Iphones the images in the manual slideshow are not opening. will you please help? here is the code of the not opened ones:

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
                <img id ="0" src="" style="width:100%; height: 500px;">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
                <img id ="1" src="" style="width:100%; height: 500px;">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
                <img id ="2" src="" style="width:100%; height: 500px;">
            </div>
            
            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
                <img id ="3" src="" style="width:100%; height: 500px;">
            </div>
            
            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
                <img id ="4" src="" style="width:100%; height: 500px;">
            </div>
            

            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides( - 1)">❮</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

        </div>
        <br>

        <div style="text-align:center">
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> 
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span> 
            
        </div>
```

CSS part:

```
.slideshow-container {
    max-width:85%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
  }
  /* Next & previous buttons */
  .prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
  }
  
  /* Position the "next button" to the right */
  .next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  }
  
  /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
  .prev:hover, .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  }
  
  /* Caption text */
  .text {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: solid;
  }
  
  /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
  .numbertext {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }
  
  /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
  .dot {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  }
  
  .active, .dot:hover {
    background-color: #717171;
  }
  
  /* Fading animation */
  .fade {
    
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
  }
  
  @keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4
    }
  
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
  }
```

[here you can check  the website](https://findlebchalet.website)
the images in this part are the ones not opening [view chalet](https://findlebchalet.website/ViewChalet.php?chaletname=beity)

I tried to change the manual slideshow into automatic but also the images didn't open

Comment: The images seem to be loading for me on mobile. Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: When I checked on safari, it only opens a little late, I couldn't see any problem. but if you use Swiper.js, I think you won't have a problem.

Comment: Even in this page the images are opened? [click here](https://findlebchalet.website/ViewChalet.php?chaletname=beity)